# How to add a cookie to save style selected by user Jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies, stylesheet, setcookie, css

I have a styleswitcher added to my site and i would like to add a cookie that saves the last style selected by the user. I have this code, could someone guide me in the process?

Thanks for reading!

I have this code to switch styles on my site:

HTML to call main style and main color

```
    <style type="text/css"> @import url("style.css");</style>
    <link href="yellow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Yellow Theme" />
```

Then i call the scripts as usual

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Each button has this:

```
    <a class="colorbox colorred" href="?theme=red" title="Red Theme"><img src="red.png" width="x" height="x" /></a>
    <a class="colorbox colorblack" href="?theme=black" title="Black Theme"><img src="black.png" width="x" height="x" /></a>
```

Now here is the script.js code:

```
    google.load("jquery", "1.5.2");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
    {

    // Color changer
    $(".colorblack").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href", "black.css");
        return false;
    });

    $(".colorred").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href", "red.css");
        return false;
    });



        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Untested:

```
$(function() {

    if($.cookie("style") !== null) {
        $('link').attr('href', $.cookie("style"));
    }

    $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var css = $(this).attr('href');
            css = css.split('=');
            $('link').attr('href', ''+ css[2] +'.css');
            $.cookie("style", ""+ css[2] +".css", { path: '/', expires: 365 });
        });
    });

});
```

It will require the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).

Comment: Hi, Thanks, i tested it and didn't worked. But I already found a solution. It's not jquery only php but it works perfect